# Trouble setting UISwitch to stored NSUserDefaults value

Tags: ios5, uiswitch

I am running into a problem whereby I am unable to retain the state of a UISwitch in my app. I think the problem is I've been trying so many different examples from different tutorials and code sources to get this working, and I'm just not seeing the complete picture.

I've set up a user preferences screen, relevant code is:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Trying here to check whether user has run app previously, and if not set default switch value (as defined in IB)
NSString *firstRunValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"testSwitch"];
if (!firstRunValue) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"testSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

return YES;
}
```

OptionsViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *testSwitch;
```

OptionsViewController.m

```
@synthesize testSwitch;

.
.
.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Here's the issue - following line does NOT set switch as expected from defaults...
[testSwitch setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"testSwitch"] animated:NO];

}

.
.
.

- (IBAction)updateTest:(id)sender {
// Action called when switch is clicked to save new state, Log shows 0 or 1 as expected
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[sender isOn] forKey:@"testSwitch"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"testSwitch"]);
}

.
.
.

- (IBAction)saveOptions:(id)sender {

// When user clicks "Save" and exits, I synch defaults and dump them, again output is as expected
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If someone could let me know where I'm going wrong (in English rather than in Objective-C!) I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what you get from `NSString *firstRunValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"testSwitch"];` after the first run? You are trying to get a string from a boolian value. I don't know what would happen there.

Comment: I'm not sure where these NSUserDefaults are stored, I can't see them anywhere but if I dump it in NSLog it looks blank...no value stored at all. But although that's obviously also an issue, it shouldn't matter should it? It's still OFF by default in IB, and when I switch it on it's not retaining that state.

Comment: Yes, because `if (!firstRunValue)` is always true. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *firstRunValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"firstRun"];

if (!firstRunValue) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"BlaBla" forKey:@"firstRun"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"testSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error "No visible @interface for 'NSUserDefaults' declares the selector 'setString:forKey:'"?

Comment: I edited my answer. `setString:forKey:` does not exist. It's `setObjekt:forKey:`.

Comment: Thanks dasdom, that fixed the error - the code all runs OK now but it's still not setting the switch correctly. When I run the app it's off by default (as set physically in IB and now as a pref in appDelegate too), if I switch it on and save, I get the correct settings dumped into the log but when I go back into the options screen it's still off...

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);` in `viewDidLoad` to check whether the setting is still in the user defaults.

Comment: Yes, it's set to either 0 or 1 correctly there, so it's definitely the [testSwitch setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"testSwitch"] animated:NO]; line in viewDidLoad that doesn't seem to be doing the job...

Comment: Ok then, try to put this line of code into `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid - I moved the NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]); line there too and it's definitely showing the correct stored value, but the switch isn't reflecting that.

Comment: Ok, put the following into `updateTest`: `NSLog(@"%@ %@", sender, testSwitch);` and check the addresses of these objects. I assume that the connection between IB and testSwitch isn't set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this...I added that line and got "<UISwitch: 0xb5ba9d0; frame = (205 121; 79 27); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb5ba9a0>> (null)", the log line afterwards (NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"testSwitch"]);) gives 1

Comment: Ok, this means `testSwitch` is pointing to nil. Please make again the connection (Ctrl-drag) between the switch in IB and `testSwitch` in your interface file and make sure that you call the right initializer (`initWithNibName:...`).

Comment: OK I ctrl-dragged again, it's now: - (IBAction)updateTest:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", sender, testSwitch);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[sender isOn] forKey:@"testSwitch"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"testSwitch"]);
}

Comment: How do you create the OptionsViewController in your code? Did you connect the `testSwitch` outlet with the switch in IB?

Comment: OptionsViewController was just a new Objective-C class file as a subclass of UIViewController - OptionsViewController.h has @interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController at the top. I'm not sure what you mean by the testSwitch outlet? The same file has  /@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *testSwitch; at the top. It was all done automatically from StoryBoard so I assume it's correct.

Comment: The `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *testSwitch;` is in OptionsViewController.h. Is that correct? Is in the space left from this line a circle with a dot in it?

Comment: Yes that's correct, the file is: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/@interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController

/@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *testSwitch;

/@end

Comment: Is there a circle with a dot?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas now.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help dasdom - this is my first time here, how can I credit you for your time and patience here? I think I will try this from scratch using the regular view controller instead of a custom one, see if that helps - I'll post back if I find my error anywhere..!